# type script : window.open().document.write() is 'possible null '

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am coding in **Vue** and **Typescript**

I have this code in my Vue component

```
const WinPrint = window.open(.,.,.) 

WinPrint.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html> ....`)
```

but I have this **error**

[image]

how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open` [can return null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value) in some cases. By the error you mention, TypeScript is warning you that you might be accessing some properties of `null` there. You need to check for the `null` case in your code. Something like

```
const WinPrint = window.open(.,.,.);

if (!WinPrint) {
    // handle the case when the window could not be opened here
} else {
    WinPrint.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html> ....`)
}
```

This will make the TypeScript see that the `WinPrint` is defined in the `else` branch.